# ERRO SQLSERVER em aplicação C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, tcpclient

Estou com um problema relacionado ao banco de dados SQLSERVER.

Tento conectar de um ponto para o servidor e aparece o erro:

> Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao estabelecer conexão com o
>   SQL Server. O servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível.
>   Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e se o SQL Server está
>   configurado para permitir conexões remotas

Obs 1 : O banco de dados está "correndo" normalmente no local(servidor).

Obs 2 : Após bateria de testes, a configuração TCP/IP está OK. (PORTA 1433 OK)

Obs 3 : Consigo acessar normalmente também via IIS.

Obs 4 : Mudei a base de dados para outro servidor e funcionou normalmente.

Obs 5 : Estava funcionando até ontem ....

Obs 6 : Em 2 pontos físicos ocorreu o problema.

Obs 7 : Pinguei normalmente dos pontos físicos para o servidor(ok)

base :

```
Data Source=192.168.1.1;
Initial Catalog=banco;
User ID=sa;
pwd=senha;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
Connection Reset=True;
Connection Lifetime=600
```

Comment: Qual o nome da instancia e qual a string de conexão está usando? Por favor, poste na pergunta

Comment: Na realidade Felipe estava usando diretamente e somente o ip como caminho , pois só estava com 1 instância habilitada (SQLEXPRESS). Caso eu estiver errado pode me corrigir!

Comment: Sql Server não "gosta muito" de IP. Troque pelo nome da instância que deve funcionar. Mas passe o nome completo.

Comment: Não, não acho que esteja errado. Na verdade, eu já tentei conectar via IP e nunca consegui. Acho que pq meu SQL SERVER não estava configurado pra tal. Tentou usar o nome da instancia? Pois o nome da instancia leva o nome do servidor

Answer (score 4):

Verifique duas coisas através do SQL Server Management Studio:

[image: Security]
[image: Connections]

Como é SQL Server Express, possivelmente é preciso especificar o nome da instância:

```
Data Source=192.168.1.1\SQLEXPRESS;
Initial Catalog=banco;
User ID=sa;
pwd=senha;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
Connection Reset=True;
Connection Lifetime=600
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido.  Era o firewall . apesar das regras de entrada do sql estarem corretas , após o desligamento do servidor isso ocorreu . Desativamos o firewall e funcionou.

Answer (score -1):

Tenta assim:

```
data source=Máquina\Instancia;
initial catalog=Nome_Banco;
persist security info=True;
user id=usuario;
password=senha;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
App=EntityFramework" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Dessa forma comigo, nunca fiquei na mão. Copia essa string e altere para sua necessidade e tente.