# Conexão remota, C# com SQL Server (2008)

Tags: c#, sql-server, connectionstring

Sou iniciante em C#, e estou tentando conectar remotamente minha aplicação C# com um banco SQL Server que está em outro PC (o PC não está na mesma rede, é do meu amigo), mas ela está dando erro. A antes que falem que eu já configurei o *firewall*, já liberei a porta.

ConnectionString:

```
<add name="connectionString" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
connectionString="Data Source = xxx.xxx.xx.xx\nomeDoHost\(instacia padrão SQLEXPRESS), (porta padrão 1433);
Network Library = DBMSSOCN; 
Initial Catalog = nome do banco;
User ID = usuario;Password = senha"/>
```

Só pra ter certeza o ip que vai no xxx.xxx.xx.xx ali é o que eu encontro aqui né : http://www.meuip.com.br/

Exceção:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: [Já tentou isto?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/72222/erro-sqlserver-em-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-c/72247#72247)

Comment: Já tentei isso também, já tentei aquele lance de configura o TCP/IP pelo SQL Server Configuration Manager também @Cigano Morrison Mendez

Comment: Pode ser muita coisa. O roteador dele, por exemplo, se não tiver uma regra para a porta 1433, não vai funcionar.

Comment: Pode ser que o que eu vou falar,alguns discordem e etc... Mas sempre tive problemas de conexão com o SqlServer passando o IP. Eu costumo passar o nome_da_máquina_completo\instância. Dessa forma deixei de ter problemas de conexão. Bem, essa é minha experiência.

Comment: Uma dica, é mais fácil colocar o servidor em um servidor SQL grátis do que toda essa complicação.

Comment: Obrigado a todos que tentaram ajudar as dicas me ajudaram a achar o problema, vlw, ta funcionando aqui tranquilo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filipe, o processo é bem simples, tenho este ambiente aqui.

O que você deve fazer, no PC do seu amigo, tem que liberar a porta de conexão, recomendo utilizar outra sem ser a padrão do SQL, utilize qualquer uma, eu utilizo a 25266.

Dai no pc dele você deve abrir a porta no firewall conforme imagem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
E no sql configuration manager conforme imagem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
E liberar também na instancia SQL dele o acesso a conexão remotas conforme imagem.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Feito isso, em seu webconfig, você deve informar o IP **dele** junto com a porta. ex: 189.55.26.85,25266 ou utilizar os serviços de atualização dinamica de DNS como o no-ip (como eu uso aqui) idevweb.no-ip.org,25266.

connectionString="189.55.26.85,25266" ou connectionString="idevweb.no-ip.org,25266"

E tudo funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Boa cara, nem pensei no DNS vou tentar fazer com um DNS no no-ip, mas esses passos que vc disse ai eu ja fiz só que com a Porta Padrão 1433, do SQL, e msm assim da exceção

Comment: Isso mesmo, por isso eu recomendei utilizar outra porta, por que na porta padrão não sei explicar o motivo, mas parece que existe um bloqueio, ou trm que configura melhor o configuration manager.